# How to use conditional add_action for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am having a small issue where i need to call add_action method which is conditional. Basically here, first checking whether the plugin active or not by admin_init action. If true then i need another add_action call from that action.

Please find the scenario what i am looking for:

```
    function check_some_other_plugin() {
        if ( is_plugin_active('some-plugin.php') ) {
                //if true then vc_before_init action will run
                add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'vc_master_home_slider' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'check_some_other_plugin' );

    function vc_master_home_slider() {
        //my stuff
    }
```

I am really eager to know how this things can be possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just put the contents of the `vc_master_home_slider()` function within the first function?

Comment: because `vc_master_home_slider()` should be hooked on that PLUGIN `vc_before_init` action